# Syntax highlighting for vb.net tag

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, syntax-highlighting

Can we get VB.NET syntax highlighting working for the [vb.net](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vb.net) tag?

I thought it was working previously, maybe something broke just recently?

Comment: Can you link the question/Answer where it is not working? Have you tried using the Language specific tag in the code block?

Comment: It's all of them. The `language` markup tag does work, however.

Comment: As far as I know, if the language tag is not present, the language is inferred from the tags on the question,  and if nothing suitable is found then it tries to figure it out from the code.

Comment: That's what this question is about. Questions tagged `vb.net` are not getting automatic syntax highlighting like they used to (pretty sure they used to anyways).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, the code highlighting for the tag was set to `<none>` instead of `default`. I've gone and fixed that now, colors should now display properly for questions with the tag.